# How to pass data from two retrofit requests to a single recyclerview adapter

Tags: java, android, google-maps, retrofit, google-places-api

Newbie here - As practice, I am using `google places` to search for `nearby` restaurants and get their details . I am also using `google place details` to get more info about the specific restaurant. I am using `Retrofit` to parse the data.

**The problem**:
I have three `ArrayList`, `restaurantName`, `restaurantAddress`, and `restaurantPhoneNum`.  I cannot pass all three `ArrayLists` into my `recyclerview`  adapter.

**Get Nearby restaurants method:**

```
private void getNearbySearchUrl(final double latitude, final double longitude, final String nearbyPlace){

    MapInterface retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build().create(MapInterface.class);

    Call<Result> call = retrofit.getResults("65.9667,-18.5333", PROXIMITY_RADIUS, "restaurant", placesKey);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Result>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Result> call, Response<Result> response) {
            ArrayList<String> restaurantName = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> restaurantAddress = new ArrayList<>();
            GetNearbyPlaces b = new GetNearbyPlaces();

            for(int i = 0; i <= response.body().getResults().size() - 1 ; i++) {
                restaurantName.add(response.body().getResults().get(i).getName());
                restaurantAddress.add(response.body().getResults().get(i).getVicinity());

                //get telephone number through this method
                getPlaceDetailsUrl(response.body().getResults().get(i).getPlaceId());

            }

            Collections.reverse(restaurantName);
            Collections.reverse(restaurantAddress);

            adapter = new RestaurantListAdapter(restaurantName, restaurantAddress,
                    response.body().getResults().size());
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Result> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("Matt", "fail");
        }
    });
}
```

**Get more info about the restaurant method:**

```
public String getPlaceDetailsUrl(final String placeId) {
    final String mPlace = placeId;

    MapInterface retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build().create(MapInterface.class);

    Call<Result> call = retrofit.getPlaceDetails(placeId, placesKey);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Result>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Result> response) {
            ArrayList<String> restaurantPhoneNum = new ArrayList<>();
            if (response.body().getResult().getFormattedPhoneNumber() == null ){
                return;
            }
            restaurantPhoneNum.add(response.body().getResult().getFormattedPhoneNumber());

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Result> call, Throwable t) {
            return;
        }
    });
}
```

**Adapter:**

```
public class RestaurantListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RestaurantListAdapter.RestaurantListHolder> {
    ArrayList<String> restaurantName = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> restaurantAddress = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> restaurantPhoneNum = new ArrayList<>();

private int restaurantCount;

public RestaurantListAdapter(ArrayList<String> resName, ArrayList<String> resAddress,
                             int resCount){
    restaurantName = resName;
    restaurantAddress = resAddress;
    restaurantCount = resCount;
}

public RestaurantListAdapter(ArrayList<String> resPhoneNum){
    restaurantPhoneNum = resPhoneNum;
}



@Override
public RestaurantListHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.restaurant_list_item, parent, false);
    RestaurantListHolder viewHolder = new RestaurantListHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RestaurantListHolder holder, int position) {
    Log.d("Matt1", String.valueOf(position) + " size:" + String.valueOf(restaurantName.size()) + restaurantName.toString());
    holder.bindView(position);
}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return restaurantCount;
}

public class RestaurantListHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView mRestaurantName;
    public TextView mAddress;
    public TextView mPhone;
    public TextView mDistance;
    public ImageView mRestaurantPic;

    public RestaurantListHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mRestaurantName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvRestaurantName);
        mAddress = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvAddress);
        mPhone = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPhone);
    }
    public void bindView(int arrayNum){
        mRestaurantName.setText(restaurantName.get(arrayNum));
        mAddress.setText(restaurantAddress.get(arrayNum));
        mPhone.setText("123 123 123 123 ");
        mRestaurantPic.setImageResource(R.drawable.rzkibble_chinese);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Two ways : 1. If you want to update your adapter in two iterations (early ready to interact with user list) then keep a common object to feed adapter from both calls. 2. If you want to show complete information after both calls then make calls in synchronous order and feed all information in one object and hand it over to adapter to draw. ... i hope it makes sense to you :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first advice, try to think about it a little bit on your own. I know that you know how to solve this :).

Your question is left unclear:

- you want to update adapter after both requests are executed
- you will update adapter after each request

I suppose that you want to implement this in a first way.
You need to have the logic which executes requestOne, executes requestTwo and when both requests are **successful**, update adapter. You can do this with some global flags *arePlacesLoaded* and *areDetailsLoaded* and to have third method which receives request result and inspects these flags.

A manual way (pseudo)

```
boolean arePlacesLoaded;
boolean areDetailsLoaded;

void loadPlaces(){
    if(success){
        arePlacesLoaded = true;
        savePlaces(places)
        updateAdapter()
    }
}

void loadDetails(){
    if(success){
        areDetailsLoaded = true;
        saveDetails(details)
        updateAdapter()
    }
}

void updateAdaper(){
    if(arePlacesLoaded && areDetailsLoaded){
        adaper.onDataChange(places, details);
    }
}
```

You can use some queues where you put requests and once the requests are executed and queue is empty -> update adapter.

Another, better way would be with usage of RxJava and its **zipWith** operator, where implementation takes few lines only (having in mind that retrofit is moved somewhere to core of the app)
Here is a marble diagram of this operator:
[image: zipWith marble]

So, request one executes, and then request two. You will provide a function which is going to merge data into some better object called Hotel, and you will feed the adapter with the array of Hotel objects.